# How do you delete all previous versions of a published npm package and use the last published version as version 1.0.0?

Tags: npm, npm-package

How do you delete all previous versions of a published npm package and use the last published version as version 1.0.0?

I published a npm package as a public package, but problem is that all versions from 1.0.0 and 1.0.8 don't work at all and only contains package.json. How do you delete all previous versions and republish the working version 1.0.9 as version 1.0.0?

Answer (score 2):

To unpublish a single package version, run `npm unpublish <package_name>@<version>`

If all the versions of a package can be unpublished, you can unpublish all versions at once by running:

```bash
npm unpublish <package-name> --force
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish

It's working in my ubuntu 21.04 with
npm 8.3.1

Comment: Running this deleted all versions. It's like the @{version} part was ignored

Comment: @nelson-javier-avila: This is a dangerous answer; you do indeed say that it would unpublish **all** versions but you should add a clearer big disclaimer, see the comment above for an example of how it could be misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not possible** to do what you're asking for.

As you can read [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish#considerations):

> Once `package@version` has been used, you can never use it again. You must publish a new version even if you unpublished the old one.

Your only choice here is to keep publishing the package using 1.0.9 (or whatever version you left the package at).
If you're not comfortable with the older versions published, you can unpublish them manually using `npm unpublish <package_name>@<package_version> --force`.

Beware that you must meet the [unpublish criteria](https://docs.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish#packages-published-less-than-72-hours-ago) in order to successfully use the unpublish command. If you do not meet those conditions, you may use `npm deprecate <package>@<version> "<message>"` instead.

Answer (score -1):

you can [unpublish the package](https://docs.npmjs.com/unpublishing-packages-from-the-registry)

> **Unpublishing a single version of a package**
>
> To unpublish a single version of a package, run the following command, replacing `<package-name>`with the name of your package, and `<version>` with your version number:
>
> `npm unpublish <package-name>@<version>`
>
> **Unpublishing an entire package**
>
> To unpublish an entire package, run the following command, replacing `<package-name>` with the name of your package:
>
> `npm unpublish <package-name> -f`